# xaml styling based on enum field in object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums, styles

I have a collection of objects like so:

```
public enum ObjectType
{
   Type1,
   Type2
}

public class MyObject
{
   ...
   public ObjectType ObjType;
   public string Header;
   ...
}
```

One of the styles I have from an example app is:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type inf:MyObject}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
    </Style>
```

How can I create separate styles constrained on the ObjectType enum field? I.E. have a separate style for a MyObject with an ObjType set to Type1 vs Type2?

My fields do implement INotifyPropertyChanged, this is just some brief sample code

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably do this via triggers:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type inf:MyObject}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObjType}" Value="Type1">
            <!-- A bunch of setters -->
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObjType}" Value="Type2">
            <!-- Another bunch of setters -->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Separation is probably not possible.

Well, you can create separate styles but you would need to apply them manually using the ResourceKey:

```
<Style x:Key="Type1Style" TargetType="{x:Type inf:MyObject}"
                          BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type inf:MyObject}}">
    <!-- Setters for type1 -->
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Type2Style" TargetType="{x:Type inf:MyObject}"
                          BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type inf:MyObject}}">
    <!-- Setters for type2 -->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try binding style property to the enum property,
using a value converter.